# Добавление второй Y-оси к графику JavaFX LineChart

Tags: javafx, график

Добрый день.

Я делаю проект с использованием JavaFX. Мне нужно добавить вторую шкалу к своему графику на LineChart с правой стороны.

Пробовал делать это с помощью JFreeChart. Но они на основе awt и для задания цвета, форм и прочего использую библиотеки awt. А в остальном проекте у меня используются библиотеки от JavaFX, что делает невозможным этот способ.

Быть может кто-то знает простой способ добавить вторую шкалу на Y-ось к графику используя только JavaFX?

[image: График с одной Y-осью в настоящий момент]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Простого способа нет.

Можно сымитировать ось расположив в `HBox` `LineChart` и `NumberAxis` с учетом отступов( вручную подгонять придется, отсутствие автосайза и т.п. ) или подложив один меньший `LineChart` под другой в `StackPane`( работа с двумя чартами ).

Есть готовое решение [MultipleAxesLineChart](https://gist.github.com/MaciejDobrowolski/9c99af00668986a0a303) взятый [отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9667405/how-to-draw-multiple-axis-on-a-chart-using-javafx-charts) ( код так себе там если честно ).

Есть проект на `Canvas` от HanSolo - [charts](https://github.com/HanSolo/charts). Там в демке есть пример.